# Can't set the background color of Action Bar with theme Holo Dark

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have a custom actionbar XML file where the following code is present:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

And in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file I have:

`android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >`

When I open the app, the `MainActivity` is trigged and for a short period of time I can see a red actionbar, just like I set it. However, when the game actually starts (goes to another activity `StartGameActivity`), the action bar color changes to black (because of the Holo theme, I suppose).

This is the code for my StartGameActivity activity in the manifest:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".activities.StartGameActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="me.sgtpeppers.instagenio.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

What is wrong with my code, people? I appreciate any help, I am new to Android and I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Comment: did you add `android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"` to the `application` tag or the `activity` one?

Comment: @yaa110 yes I did. Added to both of them :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added your styles and to the activity-tag: 
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"

.. and it looks fine here, even if switching activities. 
Maybe inside your StartGameActivity, the actionbar-styling is overridden. 
Do you have another custom actionbar/menu in there?

Comment: I have a menu `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share" />
</menu>`

Comment: Hi, you are right, I was doing something stupid in my activity, calling `getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(null);`
 thanks!